# Word: Automatically select text block on click

Tags: ms-word, office365

Is it possible to have Word (Office 365) automatically select a block of text when a user clicks into it?

For example we have instructions in a document that might be `[insert updated fee here]`

In general the whole block needs to be replaced with the new text.

These blocks are formatted in a specific way, so the method could be associated with a specific style, but as there are likely multiple instances of the style we would only want to update the one clicked on, not all instances.

I can't find a native method, so are we looking at a macro on each template that this occurs on?

Comment: Look to the information about being On Topic and the guidelines. This is a programming forum, not a forum on how to use an application. For native methods, look into using a macrobutton prompt or a content control. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#MacroButtonField -- http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#MacroButtonPrompt -- Neither method requires any programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert your text blocks into Rich Text Content Controls as the placeholder texts for those content controls. No code required.

Comment: Ha. I'd assumed that was what I had done, but it turns out that a) you can't paste into the place holder text, and b) you need to click the second character to edit the text.

Comment: The correct way to change the placeholder text - as opposed to overwriting it - is to edit it in Design mode. Once you've done that and you switch back out of Design mode, clicking *anywhere* in the content control selects all of its content.